# I have added external lan card of intel pro/1000gt but thats not showing in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 based distro (Elementary OS Stable) My motherboard is:

Asus p5kpl-am se

The Lan Card is: Intel PRO 1000/GT Desktop Adapter

I am trying to add an external lan Card so that I can connect on Lan and Internet both at the same time. After connecting the Lan Card in PCI slot I do not find the card in the system.

The output of the ifconfig -a command is as below:

```
root@host:/home/user# ifconfig -a eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 90:e6:ba:b8:7a:be
inet addr:192.168.1.10 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::92e6:baff:feb8:7abe/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:38497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:35509 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:33402284 (33.4 MB) TX bytes:20030855 (20.0 MB) lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 RX packets:1343 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:1343 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:125398 (125.3 KB) TX bytes:125398 (125.3 KB
```

Then I ran lspci command and the output is as below:

root@host:/home/user# lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10) 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)

00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller
(rev 01)

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

Comment: have you verified the card actually works?

Comment: Ramhound thank you for your quick response. I have found that the card is fine but the bios was having some thing weird. I reset all to default in Bios and the card is appearing in ifconfig command.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the card is fine but the bios was having some thing weird. I reset all to default in Bios and the card is appearing in ifconfig command.